# Convert String to Float or Int in KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to convert app version to `Int` or `Float` for comparison.
I am using the following syntax, but it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

```
val currentVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.toFloat()
```

**Edit:** What if I need to convert "2.2" to float?

Comment: Use `VERSION_CODE` instead of `VERSION_NAME`

Comment: use VERSION_CODE ofr comparisons

Comment: Please check edit.

Comment: Why not you try `"2.2".toFloat()` and check? It returns **2.2**

Comment: Yes, it returns 2.2, but my app version had 3 decimals which was causing the confusion. @Demigod gave the required answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App version comparison can be very straightforward, like comparing versions `1.0` and `2.0`.

But sometimes it can become complicated if versions to compare are `1.0.2-rc2` and `1.0.2-rc3` or `2.0.0-beta` and `2.0.0`.In this situation, you cannot just convert your `versionName` to `Int` or `Float` type. Which is not future proof, by the way, cause most likely, `1.19` will be considered as an older version than `1.2`.

In order to make this comparison easy, you can check this library - [Version Compare (github)](https://github.com/G00fY2/version-compare). (Alternative - [Semver4j](https://github.com/vdurmont/semver4j)) I think it will handle most of the cases.

Also, you can read a bit more about versioning in this [post](https://medium.com/@maxirosson/versioning-android-apps-d6ec171cfd82).

Comment: Thanks @Demigod. Your explanation gives the required direction I need to proceed with app versioning.

Answer (score 2):

Generally a version name is written as follow : "1.0.0" ( of course you can parse the string and then get 3 numbers : "1", "0" and "0" ) so you cannot convert it into a number format. Otherwhise you could use **VERSION_CODE** it will return a number

Comment: Yeah, we can do that but lets make this simple, how can i convert "2.20" in String to float in kotlin?

Comment: Be sure that your string can be parse into Float format ( it will be 2.20 and not 2.20.x ) then you can call the toFloat() method. Surround your code with a try/catch to check the format of your string

Comment: Yes, that helps too, but @Demigod gave new direction for app versioning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you got `NumberFormatException` it means that the string is not a valid representation of a number.

Your BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE is a valid Int, can you use it?